# rsync does not create destination folder as I want

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I have the following text file

```
...
/a/b/c/f1
/a/b/c/f2
...
/a/b/c/d1
...
```

where `f1` and `f2` are files, while `d1` is a directory. I would like to copy the exact hiearchy in my destination folder (`/z`).

With bash, for each line `lr` readed from the text file, my script runs (I omitted the options for the sake of simplicity)

`rsync $lr/ /z/$lr`

The folder is copied correctly because I obtain `/z/a/b/c/d1`. Unfortunately, for the files results

```
/z/a/b/c/f1/f1
/z/a/b/c/f2/f2
```

How could I solve this problem using the same above-mentioned `rsync` invokation for both the files and directories?

Comment: "_I omitted the options for the sake of simplicity_" - please don't do that. The options for a command like rsync are really important

Comment: And really complex.  ~150 distinct rsync options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rsync the files manually. Use the `--files-from=` option to include your text file.

Rules for directories:

- Only the directory is created if the path doesn't end with a trailing `/`
- To sync a dir's contents, add a trailing `/` or option `--recursive` / `-r` alternatively

If you use option `-a` and want recursion, you need to add `-r` additionally. Make sure the paths in the file are relative to the source dir (with or without leading `/`).

A minimal example for your input would be:

```
rsync --files-from=textfile / /z
```

If you need to modify/filter the text file beforehand, you can pass it from stdin to rsync, e.g.

```
your_command textfile | rsync --files-from=- / /z
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at your `rsync` command. You've omitted the options - which are important - so I've assumed you're using either `-a` (`--archive`) or `-rt` (`--recursive --times`), and I'll add `-v` (`--verbose`) for convenience too.

You're reading source files from this text file:

> ```
> /a/b/c/f1
> /a/b/c/f2
> ...
> /a/b/c/d1
> ```

And you have this template, where each line from the text file is read into `$lr`:

> ```
> rsync $lr/ /z/$lr
> ```

Let's apply an equivalent of lines `f1` and `d1` to your templated command and see what we have:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/733765
cd /tmp/733765
mkdir -p a/b/c/d1
touch a/b/c/{f1,f2,d1/f3} z

rsync -av a/b/c/f1/ z/a/b/c/f1
rsync -av a/b/c/d1/ z/a/b/c/d1
```

Straightaway we can see that with the information shown to us, the *file* `f1` will not get copied. Instead we get this error,

```
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/tmp/733765/a/b/c/f1" failed: Not a directory (20)
```

If you see `f1` in the destination it must have been copied using some other solution, perhaps an earlier attempt at using `rsync`.

Similarly, `d1` won't get copied to the destination unless you have already created the directory path `z/a/b/c`:

```
rsync: [Receiver] mkdir "/tmp/733765/z/a/b/c/d1" failed: No such file or directory (2)

mkdir -p z/a/b/c
rsync -av a/b/c/d1/ z/a/b/c/d1

created directory z/a/b/c/d1
./
f3

sent 122 bytes  received 71 bytes  128.67 bytes/sec
```

There's something not right about the information in your question. If we ignore the `rsync` command and concentrate on the source data set, you can use `rsync` to read the source data set directly:

```
rsync --files-from /path/to/source_data_file -arv . z/
```

This may seem slightly strange because usually `-a` includes `-r`. However because we are using `--files-from` and you have directories specified in the source data file we need to specify `-r` explicitly to tell `rsync` to recurse into the listed source directories. (Without this you'll only get named files copied.)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very insightful!